# Cut optimisation algorithm

Tags: algorithm, optimization, cut

Me and some of my friends at college were assigned a practical task of developing a net application for optimization of cutting rectangular parts from some kind of material. Something like apps in [this](http://www.freedownloadmanager.org/downloads/cut_optimization_software/) list, but more simplistic. Basically, I'm interested if there is any source code for this kind of optimization algorithms available on the internet. I'm planning to develop the app using Adobe Flex framework. The programming part will be done in Actionscript 3, ofc. However, I doubt that there are any optimization samples for this language. There may be some for Java, C++, C#, Ruby or Python and other more popular languages, though(then I'd just have to rewrite it in AS). So, if anyone knows any free libs or algorithm code samples that would suit me, I'd like to hear your suggestions. :)

Answer (score 6):

This sounds just like the [stock cutting problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutting_stock_problem) which is *extermely hard!*  The best solutions use linear programming (typically based on the simplex method) with column generation (which, even after years on a constraint solving research project I feel unequipped to give a half decent explanation).  In short, you won't want to try this approach in Actionscript; consequently, with whatever you do implement, you shouldn't expect great results on anything other than small problems.

The best advice I can offer, then, is to see if you can cut the source rectangle into strips (each of the width of the largest rectangles you need), then subdivide the remainder of each strip after the "head" rectangle has been removed.

I'd recommend using branch-and-bound as your optimisation strategy.  BnB works by doing an exhaustive tree search that keeps track of the best solution seen so far.  When you find a solution, update the bound, and backtrack looking for the next solution.  Whenever you know your search takes you to a branch that you know cannot lead to a better solution than the best you have found, you can backtrack early at that point.

Since these search trees will be very large, you will probably want to place a time limit on the search and just return your best effort.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I had trouble finding examples when I wanted to do the same for the woodwoorking company I work for. The problem itself is NP-hard so you need to use an approximation algorithm like a first fit or best fit algorithm. 
Do a search for 2d bin-packing algorithms. The one I found, you sort the panels biggest to smallest, then add the to the sheets in in order, putting in the first bin it will fit. Sorry don't have the code with with me and its in vb.net anyway.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/30675502)

Comment: @MarioPetrovic: That’s a strange review reason to give for a post that doesn’t include a link. I guess your point is that the answer suggests searching for something, and that’s a bit like a link without actually including a link?

Comment: I guess it was suppose to be a review to be a comment. My bad

Comment: @MarioPetrovic The question itself should be closed as asking for software recommendations.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense.