# Auto arrange controls in tiles mode in Panel

Tags: c#, winforms, panel, tile

I have numerous `Button` in a `Panel` and would like to rearrange them in order to get tiles.

[image]

What efficient algorithm can do that?

**UPDATE**

In order words I'm looking for the same result as thumbnails displayed in Google Images result page.

Comment: `FlowLayoutPanel` control with `FlowDirection = LeftToRight` will do this for you.

Comment: Do you mean you want to optimize the placement so you get the least wasted space at the end of each row? And if so, are you sure that's a good idea? Usually the placement of buttons on a UI has something to do with the purpose of the buttons, so buttons that do similar things are grouped together.

Comment: @B0Andrew this doesn't optimize the placements.

Comment: @RenniePet Right, I actually want to optimize the placement. I would like to reproduce something like a cloud tag.

Comment: Do buttons have a display order priority? Are the margins predefined or the algorithm should adjust them for a better result? Do all buttons have the same height or the algorithm should take care of arrangement on both `x` and `y` axes?

Comment: There is no order priority, margins are predefined, and all buttons have same height.

Comment: I think this is a very general optimization problem. It's related to cutting out dress or suit material from a roll of cloth, or cutting out needed pieces of wood from sheets of plywood. Except your case is simpler since it is basically 1-dimensional instead of 2-dimensional.

Comment: Some links that might help: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/612194/Genetic-algorithm-for-optimal-linear-cutting http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4360637/cut-optimisation-algorithm http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/706136/Csharp-Bin-Packing-Cutting-Stock-Solver

Comment: I just discovered that it's named "bin-packing problem", and it's not so easy to solve: http://www.cs.amherst.edu/alglab/exactbinpacklab/index.html