# Algorithm for computing a sum with multiples of specific values

Tags: algorithm

I am attempting to compute a known sum or closest value to that sum using the multiples of a subset of numbers. In this approach I want to minimize the multiples or coefficient.

For instance if I have the number `120` and I have a set of `50s` and `20s`, I would get

```
120 = 2*50 + 1*20.
```

The set of numbers can be limited however, so if I only have `1x50` and `6x20s`, I will get

```
120 = 6*20.
```

Furthermore if I have only `5x20s`, since I want to minimize the coefficient, I would have

```
110 = 1*50 + 3*20.
```

Note that in this case, the value is the closest value to the sum. If the sum can be achieved, that takes precedence over having the closest value to the sum with less number of multiples.

Is there a known algorithm to achieve this result?

Comment: Did you read about generating functions?

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm you seek is often referred to as a 'greedy' algorithm.  You can read about the theory and how it works here:  [Cut optimisation algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4360637/8569576)

A common use case that is similar to your specific request is a cut length optimization used in manufacturing.  Check out this Wikipedia article which discusses the problem, and the calculus behind the optimization algorithm needed:  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutting_stock_problem

For an example of this in action, try out this spreadsheet with the scripted algorithm as a macro: http://www.cutoptimizer.com